# i have a list of data which i converted to list of Ul and li , now i want this list to displayed as tree in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have converted my list data into unorderedlist and now i want them to be displayed into tree.

My requirement is on click of icon the expand/collapse should happen.
Similarly when i click on the text , it should redirect to the page which i refer to.

Found some solutions where Parent was not acting as hyperlink instead it acted for expand/collapse.

This is the UL and li combinations that i have created from my arraylist, now i wanted this to be a tree.
note: All text here is a hyperlink

- company

  - workers

    - micheal
    - nikhil
    - Anjan

      - chaitra

        - caught25

          - first

            - second

              - third

Please advice me the next steps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but here's a quick example to get you started.

Because we are appending the icon to the outer edge of the list item, it allows you to still have your actual link text act as a link.

See below for a brief solution:

JS:

```
$('ul li').each(function(e) {
    // Does the list item have a nested UL?
    var children = $(this).children('ul').length;

   // If so, add an arrow icon.
   if(children)
       $(this).append('<div class="arrow">+</div>');
})

$('.arrow').click(function() {
    // Add or remove 'open' class, which shows or hides the element.
    $(this).parent('li').children('ul').toggleClass('open');
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">1</a></li>
<li><a href="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="">3</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">5</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">9</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}
```

This appends a clickable icon to the list item if it has a UL child. Then it adds a click handler for said icon to hide/ show the list elements. I take it this is what you are after?